# How does one prove that a user has locked Monero for X blocks?

Tags: transaction-unlock-time

Is there a way to do a proof-of-locked coins? I know Bitcoin has the ability to lock for X amount of blocks. Does Monero have something like this and how does a 3rd party prove that a user has locked X amount of coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove a) that a tx has locked coins by providing the tx hash of the tx which has the locked funds and b) prove you created the tx.

To prove a tx has locked funds, simply give the user the txid so they can inspect it on the blockchain (using either their own local daemon or a blockchain explorer). E.g.

```
$ monerod print_tx 6cd029...bf8c34 +json
Found in blockchain at height 1991755 (pruned)
{
  "version": 2, 
  "unlock_time": 1991815, 
  ...
}
```

Which shows that this tx is locked until block 1991815.

To prove you sent the tx, use the wallet command `get_spend_proof`:

```
[wallet]: get_spend_proof 6cd029...bf8c34
signature file saved to: monero_spend_proof
```

Then send the resulting file and txid to the user so they can verify with the wallet command `check_spend_proof`:

```
[wallet]: check_spend_proof 6cd029...bf8c34 monero_spend_proof
Good signature
```

Comment: **monerod print_tx 6cd029...bf8c34 +json** doesn't show the amount locked, but only that its locked until a certain block height. would I need to make a separate monerod call to verify the amount sent or can I just do it in the same print_tx command?

Comment: Only the sender or recipient can view *amount* and they do that in their wallet.

Comment: is there no way to publicly show the amount in a way that you don't expose your private keys? How about providing the view keys for the receiver address where the sender sends to another address they control.

Comment: Using a combination of get_reserve_proof and get_tx_proof / get_spend_proof should suffice no?